# How does one go about constructing a mixed entangled state?

Tags: entanglement

In general, an entangled state is one which cannot be decomposed as $\sum_{i}p_{i} \bigl(\rho_{i}^A\otimes\rho_{i}^B\bigr)$. But such an entangled state could still be mixed in principle.

How would one create a *mixed* entangled state? For instance, can one create such a state by tracing out one qubit or a subsystem of a pure state?

Comment: where are you getting this from? A (possibly mixed) entangled state is one that cannot be written as a convex decomposition of separable states, which has nothing to do with what you wrote. Also what do you mean by "construction" here?

Comment: From the definition of a mixed entangled state, one that cannot be written as a decomposition of mixed states. By construction I mean under what process would it emerge under. What I described above is exactly what I mean. If you trace out one qubit, you are left with $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ as stated above. This state cannot be written as a decomposition of mixed states, so I am asking if this is a mixed entangled state.  $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=\frac{1}{2}|00\rangle\langle00|+\frac{1}{2}|11\rangle\langle11|$

Comment: Do you have a reference for the definition?

Comment: Please fix your definition or otherwise clearly cite a source that's causing this confusion.

Comment: Here are two physics stack exchange posts on the matter https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/468766/can-the-reduced-state-of-a-mixed-entangled-state-be-pure https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/171881/entanglement-of-mixed-quantum-state

Comment: Here is a paper by the Horodecki's on the matter https://cds.cern.ch/record/344547/files/9801069.pdf

Comment: I've significantly revised the question to strip it down to the core answerable question, as I saw it.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap no problem, appreciated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a state which yeilds an entangled state when you trace one qubit out, is the 3-qubit "W" state:
$$ 
\lvert W_3 \rangle = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt3} \Bigl( \lvert 100 \rangle + \lvert 010 \rangle + \lvert 001 \rangle \Bigr)
$$
Taking the outer product with itself, we obtain
$$ 
\lvert W_3 \rangle\!\langle W_3 \rvert = \tfrac{1}{3} \Bigl(
\!\begin{aligned}[t]&
 \lvert 100 \rangle\!\langle 100 \rvert + \lvert 100 \rangle\!\langle 010 \rvert
 + \lvert 100 \rangle\!\langle 001 \rvert \phantom{\Big)}
 \\&+ 
 \lvert 010 \rangle\!\langle 100 \rvert + \lvert 010 \rangle\!\langle 010 \rvert
 + \lvert 010 \rangle\!\langle 001 \rvert 
 \\&+ 
 \lvert 001 \rangle\!\langle 100 \rvert + \lvert 001 \rangle\!\langle 010 \rvert
 + \lvert 001 \rangle\!\langle 001 \rvert
\Bigr) \end{aligned}
$$
If we trace out the third qubit, we then obtain the state
$$
\begin{align}
\rho = \mathrm{tr}_3\Bigl(\lvert W_3 \rangle\!\langle W_3 \rvert\Bigr)
&= \tfrac{1}{3} \Bigl(
 \lvert 10 \rangle\!\langle 10 \rvert + \lvert 10 \rangle\!\langle 01 \rvert + 
 \lvert 01 \rangle\!\langle 10 \rvert + \lvert 01 \rangle\!\langle 01 \rvert
 + \lvert 00 \rangle\!\langle 00 \rvert
\Bigr)
\\&= \tfrac{1}{3} \lvert 00 \rangle\!\langle 00 \rvert +  \tfrac{2}{3} \lvert \Psi^+ \rangle\!\langle \Psi^+ \rvert,
\end{align}
$$
where in particular $\lvert \Psi^+ \rangle = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\bigl( \lvert 01 \rangle + \lvert 10 \rangle \bigr)$ is a Bell state.

Note that $\rho$ is a rank-2 operator with different eigenvalues: any decomposition of $\rho$ as a convex combination of other density operators, can only involve terms whose eigenvectors are supported on $\mathrm{span}\,\{ \lvert 00 \rangle, \lvert \Psi^+ \rangle \}$. Any mixed tensor product density operator $\rho_A \otimes \rho_B$ has an eigenbasis consisting of two or more product states; but the only product state contained in $\mathrm{span}\,\{ \lvert 00 \rangle, \lvert \Psi^+ \rangle \}$ is the state $\lvert 00 \rangle$ itself. It follows that $\rho$ cannot be decomposed as a convex combination of products of possibly-mixed states, and is entangled.

More generally, if for $n > 1$ we define $\lvert W_n \rangle$ as the analogous $n$-term uniform superposition of standard basis states with a single 1, we may describe it as
$$ \lvert W_n \rangle = \tfrac{\sqrt{n{-}1}}{\sqrt n} \lvert W_{n{-}1}\rangle\lvert0\rangle + \tfrac{1}{\sqrt n} \lvert00\cdots0\rangle\lvert1\rangle
$$
so that
$$ \mathrm{tr}_n\Bigl(\lvert W_n \rangle\!\langle W_n \rvert\Bigr) = \tfrac{n{-}1}{n} \lvert W_{n-1} \rangle\!\langle W_{n-1} \rvert + \tfrac{1}{n} \lvert 00\cdots0\rangle\!\langle 00\cdots 0\rvert
$$
which for larger values of $n$ is closer and closer to being a pure entangled state, while still being mixed for any finite $n$.

Comment: I take it that, as @DaftWullie stated, the PT of $\frac{n-1}{n}|W_{n-1}\rangle\langle W_{n-1}|+\frac{1}{n}|00...0\rangle\langle00...0|$ will yield negative eigenvalues?

Comment: The 'if and only if' condition that he mentions holds only two-qubit states, so we should consider whether $\rho = \tfrac{2}{3} \lvert \Psi^+ \rangle \!\langle \Psi^+ \rvert + \tfrac{1}{3} \lvert 00 \rangle\!\langle 00 \rvert$ has a positive partial transpose. From the expansion of $\rho$ that I give in the standard basis, we see that it's partial transpose (on either qubit) is $\tfrac{1}{3}( \lvert 10 \rangle\!\langle 10 \rvert + \lvert 00 \rangle\!\langle 11 \rvert + \lvert 11 \rangle\!\langle 00 \rvert + \lvert 00 \rangle\!\langle 00 \rvert )$, which has eigenvalues $\pm \tfrac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

A mixed separable state is written in the form
$$
\rho=\sum_ip_i\sigma^A_i\otimes\sigma^B_i
$$
where the $\sigma_i$ are valid density matrices on a single site.

The example you give, say $\rho=\frac12|00\rangle\langle00|+\frac12|11\rangle\langle 11|$ is exactly of this form. Specifically,
$$
p_0=p_1=\frac12,\qquad \sigma^A_0=\sigma^B_0=|0\rangle\langle 0|,\qquad \sigma^A_1=\sigma^B_1=|1\rangle\langle 1|.
$$

In general, it can be tricky to definitively prove that such a decomposition does not exist. However, in the case of two-qubits, there's an if and only if condition: the state is entangled if and only if its partial transpose is not non-negative (i.e. contains a negative eigenvalue).

The classic example is the [Werner state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_state),
$$
\rho=\frac{1-p}{4}I+p|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|
$$
where $|\psi\rangle$ is a two-qubit Bell state. This can be written out as a matrix
$$
\rho=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{1-p}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1+p}{4} & -\frac{p}{2}  & 0 \\
0 & -\frac{p}{2} & \frac{1+p}{4} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1-p}{4}
\end{array}\right)
$$
If we take the partial transpose of this, we get
$$
\rho^T=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{1-p}{4} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{p}{2} \\
0 & \frac{1+p}{4} & 0  & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1+p}{4} & 0 \\
-\frac{p}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1-p}{4}
\end{array}\right)
$$
This has a negative eigenvalue if $p/2>(1-p)/4$.

Comment: what do you mean "the tensor product of *the* two mixed states"? There are many mixed states, not just the maximally mixed state $I/2$. This actually includes, for example, all pure states.

Comment: I was under the impression that, like a pure state, the criteria for a mixed state being entangled is the inability to decompose it into the product of two mixed states, regardless of structure, ie the above example I gave. I did not realise that the sum of the product was an acceptable approach.

Comment: What about the definition of it mixed entangle state being a mixture of $\sum p_{i}|\psi_{i}\rangle\langle\psi_{i}|$ where $\psi_{i}$ is itself an entangled state?

Comment: That is certainly mixed, but there's no guarantee it's entangled. For example, an equal mixture of all 4 Bell states gives the maximally mixed state, which is certainly not entangled.

Comment: I assume $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ in your example is $\frac12(|01\rangle-|10\rangle)(\langle01|-\langle10|)|$?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: Alright, so it's not as simple as finding mixed states whose elements are entangled states, but ones which( for bipartite systems anyway) will give negative eigenvalues. So $\frac14((|00\rangle+|11\rangle)(\langle00|+\langle11|)+(|01\rangle+|10\rangle)(\langle01|+\langle10|)+(|00\rangle-|11\rangle)(\langle00|-\langle11|)+(|01\rangle-|10\rangle)(\langle01|-\langle10|))+\frac14(|01\rangle-|10\rangle)(\langle01|-\langle10|)$ would be the beginnings of such a state, and then the associate probabilities would need to be corrected to get the negative eigenvalues?

Comment: No. Any valid quantum state has non-negative eigenvalues. You’re interested in the partial transpose operation, and the eigenvalues of the resultant matrix.

Comment: Right, so taking what I put there, as in the werner state, would give me a matrix, the partial transpose of which would produce negative eigenvalues, provided the associated probabilities would be corrected.